# Dev C++ - Opaque Text On Transparent Frame

Tags: dev-c++

I am a beginner c++ graphics programmer and using dev c++ as IDE. I created a simple frame with textbox and a button and called `DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea` from dwmapi.dll.
But the textbox and button show ugly transparent text. I want opaque text on textbox and button. I've searched all around but found answers for .NET c++ and not dev c++. So please help me dealing with this matter using dev c++. Efforts will be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```c
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include <windows.h>
#include <uxtheme.h>
HWND tb;
HWND btn;

typedef struct _DWM_BLURBEHIND
{
    DWORD dwFlags;
    BOOL fEnable;
    HRGN hRgnBlur;
    BOOL fTransitionOnMaximized;
} DWM_BLURBEHIND, *PDWM_BLURBEHIND;

HINSTANCE DLL = LoadLibrary("dwmapi.dll"); 
typedef HRESULT (*_DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea)(HWND hwnd,MARGINS* margins);

_DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea = (_DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea)GetProcAddress(DLL,"DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea");

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {

    switch(Message) {


        case WM_CREATE: {

            ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(),SW_HIDE);

            MARGINS margins = {-1,-1,-1,-1};
            DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(hwnd,&margins);

            tb = CreateWindow("EDIT","Text",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,5,5,574,30,hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
            btn = CreateWindow("BUTTON","Button",WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,5,50,80,30,hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);                             
            break;

        }   

        case WM_DESTROY: {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, Message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {



    WNDCLASSEX wc; /* A properties struct of our window */
    HWND hwnd; /* A 'HANDLE', hence the H, or a pointer to our window */
    MSG Msg; /* A temporary location for all messages */

    /* zero out the struct and set the stuff we want to modify */
    memset(&wc,0,sizeof(wc));
    wc.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc; /* This is where we will send messages to */
    wc.hInstance     = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor       = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);


    /* White, COLOR_WINDOW is just a #define for a system color, try Ctrl+Clicking it */

    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOWTEXT);
    wc.lpszClassName = "WindowClass";
    wc.hIcon         = LoadIcon(NULL,IDI_APPLICATION); /* Load a standard icon */
    wc.hIconSm       = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION); /* use the name "A" to use the project icon */

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Registration Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE,"WindowClass","Frame",WS_VISIBLE | WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, /* x */
        CW_USEDEFAULT, /* y */
        600, /* width */
        350, /* height */
        NULL,NULL,hInstance,NULL);

    if(hwnd == NULL) {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Window Creation Failed!","Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    /*
        This is the heart of our program where all input is processed and 
        sent to WndProc. Note that GetMessage blocks code flow until it receives something, so
        this loop will not produce unreasonably high CPU usage
    */
    while(GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0) { /* If no error is received... */
        TranslateMessage(&Msg); /* Translate key codes to chars if present */
        DispatchMessage(&Msg); /* Send it to WndProc */
    }
    return (int) Msg.wParam;

}
```